# Cache Proxy Server Python Returns 404 Error HTTP Requests

Tags: python, http, networking, proxy

i wrote a code about a basic proxy using python but i have a problem when i send a request using the proxy it responses with 404.
in the browser i write "localhost:8888/www.google.com"
while running the code below.
i tried to troubleshoot the code but i think my troubleshooting is creating the more troubles xD.
if anyone could help it will mean alot to me and thanks in advance

```
from socket import *
import sys
import re
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

serverPort = 8888
serverSocket.bind(("localhost", serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    print('Ready to serve...')
    tcpCliSock, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print('Received a connection from:', addr)
    message = tcpCliSock.recv(1024).decode()
    print('Request message:', message)
    # Extract the filename from the given message
    filename = message.split()[1].partition("/")[2]
    filetouse = "/" + filename
    print('File to use:', filetouse)

    try:
        # Check if the file exists in the cache
        with open(filetouse[1:], "r") as f:
            outputdata = f.readlines()
            print("Read from cache")
            # Send the content of the requested file to the client
            tcpCliSock.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n".encode())
            tcpCliSock.send("Content-Type: text/html\r\n".encode())
            tcpCliSock.send("\r\n".encode())
            for line in outputdata:
                print(line)
                tcpCliSock.send(line.encode())
    except IOError:
        # File does not exist in the cache, fetch it from the server
        print("File not found in cache")
        
        # Create a socket on the proxy server
        c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        hostn = message.split()[1].lstrip("/")
        print("Host : ", hostn)
        try:
            c.connect((hostn, 80))
            print("Connected to server:", hostn)
            # Send request to the server
            print("Request sent to server:")
            print(message)
            c.sendall(message.encode("utf-8"))
            
            # Receive response from the server
            response = c.recv(4096)
            print("Response from server:")
            print(response.decode("utf-8"))
            print("Response from server:")
            print(response.decode("utf-8"))
            
            for line in response.decode():
                print(line)
                tcpCliSock.send(line.encode())
                
                # Optional: You can also write the response to a file if desired
                # response_file.write(line)
                
            # Close the response file if it was opened
            # response_file.close()
            
            # Create a new file in the cache for the requested file
            with open(filetouse[1:], "w") as f:
                # Write the response to the cache file
                f.write(response.decode())
            
        except Exception as e:
            # Handle exceptions that occur while connecting to the server or making the request
            print("Illegal request")
            print(e)
                
    tcpCliSock.close()
    c.close()

serverSocket.close()
```